# Jquery phone number validation start from+30

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

** Jquery phone number validation **
Jquery phone number validation using regular expression.

valid phone number:- +30344343434,
ragex not working and error show:-
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(+30)[0-9]{9}$/: Nothing to repeat

```
$.validator.addMethod("PhoneValidation", (function(e) {
        let regex =  /^(+30)[0-9]{9}$/.test(e);
        return(regex);
    }), PHONE_VALIDATE);
```

suggest valid regex.

Comment: Do you want validation like +30xxxxxxxxx ?

Comment: i want validation like +303xxxxxxxx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
$.validator.addMethod("PhoneValidation", function (value) {
       return /^(\+30)(30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39)[0-9]{7}$/.test(value);
}, "Please enter valid number.");
```

put `\` before starting `+30` in the first bracket
And
in the second bracket, put pair with 3 which you want to validate